# Array displayed inside Html table

Tags: javascript, html

I got this code for an array an infinite array in javascript and I can add more to it delete from it update elements inside of it.
I need  to show that array as a table in html page the design does not matter I can work on that.

I am only allowed to use JavaScript not jQuery, I'm really not sure what to do here.

```js
let students = [];
let x = 0;
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let nameInputEl = document.getElementById("name");
  let idInputEl = document.getElementById("idNumber");
  let gdpaInputEl = document.getElementById("gdpa");

  // Validation for input
  inputValidation(nameInputEl.value, idInputEl.value, gdpaInputEl.value);

  // insert student
  if (x == 1) {
    insertStudent(nameInputEl.value, idInputEl.value, gdpaInputEl.value);
  }

  // Show success message
});

function inputValidation(name, id, gdpa) {
  // check for the value of each element

  if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else if (id == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else if (gdpa == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Succes101").style.display = "block";
    x = 1;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Succes101").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
}

function insertStudent(name, id, gdpa) {
  let student = {
    name: name,
    id: id,
    gdpa: gdpa,
  };
  students.push(student);
  console.log("students array: ", students);
  x = 0;
}

function showList() {
  students.forEach(element => {
    document.getElementById("showLi").innerHTML = (students);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>School Managment System</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="big-title">
      <h2 class="title">Assignment</h2>
      <span class="ligne"> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="big_box col-md-12">
      <form>
        <!-- student name -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="name" class="Name_Label">Student Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="Name_Input" id="name" placeholder="jo aqra" />
        </div>
        <!-- student name -->

        <!-- student id -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="idNumber" class="NO_Label">Student ID</label>
          <input type="number" class="NO_Input" id="idNumber" placeholder="411420876" />
        </div>
        <!-- student id -->

        <!-- student gdpa -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="gdpa" class="gp_Label">Student GDPA</label>
          <input type="number" step="0.01" class="gp_Input" id="gdpa" placeholder="3.50" />
        </div>
        <!-- student gdpa -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button id="submit" type="submit">Add</button>
          <button id="list" id="list" type="button" onclick="showList()">Show</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="ShowLi"></div>



  <div class="Error" id="Error101" aria-hidden="true"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>Please fill all the empty fields</div>
  <div class="Succes" id="Succes101" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Student added</div>

  <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this

```
document.getElementById("ShowLi").innerHTML = students
  .map(({ name, id, gdpa }) => `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${id}</td><td>${gdpa}</td></tr>`)
  .join("");
```

I added a table inside the div

```js
let students = [];
let x = 0;
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let nameInputEl = document.getElementById("name");
  let idInputEl = document.getElementById("idNumber");
  let gdpaInputEl = document.getElementById("gdpa");

  // Validation for input
  inputValidation(nameInputEl.value, idInputEl.value, gdpaInputEl.value);

  // insert student
  if (x == 1) {
    insertStudent(nameInputEl.value, idInputEl.value, gdpaInputEl.value);
  }

  // Show success message
});

function inputValidation(name, id, gdpa) {
  // check for the value of each element

  if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else if (id == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else if (gdpa == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Succes101").style.display = "block";
    x = 1;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Succes101").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
}

function insertStudent(name, id, gdpa) {
  let student = {
    name: name,
    id: id,
    gdpa: gdpa,
  };
  students.push(student);
  console.log("students array: ", students);
  x = 0;
}

function showList() {
  document.getElementById("ShowLi").innerHTML = students
    .map(({ name, id, gdpa }) => `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${id}</td><td>${gdpa}</td></tr>`)
    .join("");
  document.getElementById("showTable").classList.remove("hide");
}
```

```css
.hide { display:none }
#showTable tr td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>School Managment System</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="big-title">
      <h2 class="title">Assignment</h2>
      <span class="ligne"> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="big_box col-md-12">
      <form>
        <!-- student name -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="name" class="Name_Label">Student Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="Name_Input" id="name" placeholder="jo aqra" />
        </div>
        <!-- student name -->

        <!-- student id -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="idNumber" class="NO_Label">Student ID</label>
          <input type="number" class="NO_Input" id="idNumber" placeholder="411420876" />
        </div>
        <!-- student id -->

        <!-- student gdpa -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="gdpa" class="gp_Label">Student GDPA</label>
          <input type="number" step="0.01" class="gp_Input" id="gdpa" placeholder="3.50" />
        </div>
        <!-- student gdpa -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button id="submit" type="submit">Add</button>
          <button id="list" id="list" type="button" onclick="showList()">Show</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <table id="showTable" class="hide">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>GDPA</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="ShowLi"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>



  <div class="Error" id="Error101" aria-hidden="true"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>Please fill all the empty fields</div>
  <div class="Succes" id="Succes101" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Student added</div>

  <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it gives me an error each time I try to press the who button

Comment: Plus I want to show the table list onclick or like an event listener to it

Comment: it gives me an error                                                                                            
         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement

Comment: now this worked but I want to display it as a table and again thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: I can change to table, I use LI because you said SHowLI

Comment: yeah I name it like this at first then change it into something else later

Comment: I made a table for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
let students = [];
let x = 0;
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let nameInputEl = document.getElementById("name");
  let idInputEl = document.getElementById("idNumber");
  let gdpaInputEl = document.getElementById("gdpa");

  // Validation for input
  inputValidation(nameInputEl.value, idInputEl.value, gdpaInputEl.value);

  // insert student
  if (x == 1) {
    insertStudent(nameInputEl.value, idInputEl.value, gdpaInputEl.value);
  }

  // Show success message
});

function inputValidation(name, id, gdpa) {
  // check for the value of each element

  if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else if (id == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else if (gdpa == "") {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Succes101").style.display = "block";
    x = 1;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("Error101").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Succes101").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
}

function insertStudent(name, id, gdpa) {
  let student = {
    name: name,
    id: id,
    gdpa: gdpa,
  };
  students.push(student);
  console.log("students array: ", students);
  x = 0;
}

function showList() {
  const resultElement = document.getElementById("showli");
  while(resultElement.firstChild && resultElement.removeChild(resultElement.firstChild));
  var table = document.getElementById("showli").appendChild( document.createElement('table') );
  students.forEach((element, i) => {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    var j = 0;
    for (const v of Object.keys(element)) {
      row.insertCell(j).innerText = element[v];
      j++;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>School Managment System</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="big-title">
      <h2 class="title">Assignment</h2>
      <span class="ligne"> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="big_box col-md-12">
      <form>
        <!-- student name -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="name" class="Name_Label">Student Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="Name_Input" id="name" placeholder="jo aqra" />
        </div>
        <!-- student name -->

        <!-- student id -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="idNumber" class="NO_Label">Student ID</label>
          <input type="number" class="NO_Input" id="idNumber" placeholder="411420876" />
        </div>
        <!-- student id -->

        <!-- student gdpa -->
        <div class="from-control col-md-4">
          <label for="gdpa" class="gp_Label">Student GDPA</label>
          <input type="number" step="0.01" class="gp_Input" id="gdpa" placeholder="3.50" />
        </div>
        <!-- student gdpa -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button id="submit" type="submit">Add</button>
          <button id="list" id="list" type="button" onclick="showList()">Show</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="showli"></div>



  <div class="Error" id="Error101" aria-hidden="true"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>Please fill all the empty fields</div>
  <div class="Succes" id="Succes101" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Student added</div>

  <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: as far as I went in this it works perfectly all I need is to give it a good design and done thanks a lot

Comment: @mplungjan I tried my best I really don't know what's the problem changed everything as you said added the same things you told me to still gives me an error I know your code is shorter more simple but it's not working for me sorry.

Comment: i'm sorry, but he asked how to display the whole list out of an array and your solution is an lifetime appending, it's not what his question was. also using innerHTML is bad practice, but however